# Set Caret behind contenteditable false span inside contenteditable true div

Tags: html, position, contenteditable, caret

Is it possible to set the caret / cursor behind a span with contenteditable false inside a contenteditable true div?

Example:

```js
$('#straightHtml').html('<p><span contenteditable="false">test</span></p>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='straightHtml' contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<br>` behind the contenteditable=false span.

```
$('#straightHtml').html('<p><span contenteditable="false">test</span><br></p>')
```

Have a try:

```js
$('#straightHtml').html('<p><span contenteditable="false">test</span><br></p>')
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='straightHtml' contenteditable="true">
</div>
```